# How do I access a specific item inside of a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, drawable, checkedtextview

I am using a layout called row_layout.xml inside every listview so that each item inside the listview contains a textview and a drawable. I want to be able to click an item and change the drawable inside that specific item. How do I go about doing this?

eg

```
final ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.trackingmelistview);
    lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);

            checkedTextView.toggle();

        }
    });
```

This does not toggle the checkedtext view that I want, it would just check the boxes from top to bottom because the view arg1 is the whole list view and not the item itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` of the ListActivity.  That will give you the position of the item in the list that the user clicked on.